# If property does not exist, use default value in python

Tags: python, game-engine, physics, properties

I have a problem with my script, i want to let the user creating or not the property, but when the property is not used, blender give me an error (its normal).
i have tried things like:

```
if "myprop" not in own:
    own["myprop"] = MyValue
```

And

```
defaultValue = MyValue
value = own("myprop", defaultValue)
```

But nothing work, i allways get an error.

Maybe the second one can work, but i dont know how to use it correctly.

I have another question, my player use the Character physics, and in the physics menu, we have the Jump Force.
I want to set the Jump Force in python, i know the function for doing this is:

```
jump_speed
```

But i dont know how tu use this:

```
GameObjectSettings(bpy_struct)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract and edited from my Movement script:

```
import bge

def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

# Verifier si les propriété existent.
Verif_Prop(own)

def Verif_Prop(own):

    # Verifie si la propriété existe.
    if "VitesseMarche" not in own:
        # Non définie, utiliser la valeur par défaut.
        own["VitesseMarche"] = 0.2
```

Source (i own the script): http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?381505-FR-EN-Advanced-Moving-Script-for-the-BGE-V2-0

Comment: Shorter way is `own.setdefault("VitesseMarche", 0.2)`. Or if you don't want to modify dict where you get value you can just do `own.get("VitesseMarche", 0.2)`.

Comment: Your code replace this exactly?                                                                              if "VitesseMarche" not in own:
        own["VitesseMarche"] = 0.2